# How to import the whole text in VBS?

Tags: vbscript

When I copy the name of a file called "A B" it only search for "A" everything after the space get ignored.
Is there a way to add "+" between the words.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set X = CreateObject("htmlfile")

text = X.ParentWindow.ClipboardData.GetData("text")

WshShell.Run "cmd.exe /k start www.google.com/search?q="+text & Chr(34),0

Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Comment: What exactly does your code snippet have to do with your question?

Comment: This code import part of the text not the whole thing

Answer (score 1):

You mean your clipboard has some text where the words are separated by spaces, and you want to turn that into a string where the words connected by ampersands, so you can use it as a Google search term? Use the `Replace` function for that. Also remove the `Chr(34)` from your code snippet. It serves no purpose.

```
text = X.ParentWindow.ClipboardData.GetData("text")
text = Replace(text, " ", "+")

WshShell.Run "cmd.exe /k start www.google.com/search?q=" & text, 0
```

A more robust approach that would take care of words separated by multiple spaces and/or other whitespace characters would use a regular expression replacement.

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "\s+"
re.Global  = True

text = X.ParentWindow.ClipboardData.GetData("text")
text = re.Replace(text, "+")

WshShell.Run "cmd.exe /k start www.google.com/search?q=" & text, 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ansgar, in the beginning it didn't work but after I replaced "&" with "+" it worked perfectly, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ansgar,

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set X = CreateObject("htmlfile")
text = X.ParentWindow.ClipboardData.GetData("text")
text = Replace(text, " ", "+")
WshShell.Run "cmd.exe /k start www.google.com/search?q=" & text, 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

---

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "\s+"
re.Global  = True
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set X = CreateObject("htmlfile")
text = X.ParentWindow.ClipboardData.GetData("text")
text = re.Replace(text, "+")
WshShell.Run "cmd.exe /k start www.google.com/search?q=" & text, 0
```

Either of these two codes will work.